# reCAPTCHA not visible in Firefox - running AdBlock and ghostery.

Tags: firefox, recaptcha, captcha

Any ideas why I'm not able to see a reCAPTCHA on a site running in Firefox with Ghostery and ABP? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered that Ghostery is blocking Recaptcha as long as you have the addon enabled with the "Enhanced Anti-Tracking" enabled. I am unable to find a way to whitelist the google recaptcha domains in the settings.

Comment: A note to anyone viewing this after early 2019 - Ghostery says they released a fix so make sure you're running the latest version of the extension, or have disabled it.

Comment: and it's back. `https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/ghostery/recaptcha__de.js`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and filed a report at Ghostery. They're working on it:

> Thanks for reporting, this is something we’ve had reports of and you are correct that disabling anti-tracking is the current work around. Our dev team is looking into this to device a fix. We appreciate your patience and happy browsing!

The reason why ReCaptcha currently isn't working in combination with Ghostery's Enhanced Anti-Tracking is that one of the variables is recognised as "tracking data" by Ghostery and therefore replaced with the literal text "ghostery". After that, a javascript file is loaded without a required part of the file path and ends up as a 404: `/recaptcha/api2//recaptcha__en.js` (this should have been `/recaptcha/api2/v1545#########/recaptcha__en.js`).

**Edit 2019-01-12: In the meanwhile, Ghostery released an update that should fix this issue.**